# ElasticSearch Timeout Error: ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=60))

Tags: python, elasticsearch, multiprocessing

I have an instance of ElasticSearch running on a server. When I try to index a huge corpus using multiprocessing, I get a lot of timeout errors. It seems that the EasticSearch can handle only a few numbers of requests. I've followed the configuration suggested in the ElasticSearch website. Are there any suggestions on what should I do to increase its indexing performance for a multiprocessing setting? The index that I'm adding documents to has one shard.

Comment: We got very few details on the configuration and the bottleneck can come from a lot of points. First change, change the index.refresh_interval to -1 when first indexing(and re change it after first ingestion). But as you work in localhost, I guess you are doing a lot af IO on the same HDD or your RAM is full and your computer is swapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of works that you can do.

- First, you need to set *refresh_interval*. *Refresh interval* is the time that the added document will become available for search. If you can tolerate set it to at least 30 seconds or -1. I have read that this will increase the indexing performance by about 70%.
- The second thing that you can try is to use bulk index API instead of a single document indexing.
- Disabling swap can make an upper performance for you in some special cases.
- One of the other options that you can try is to increase the RAM size that you have assigned to your elasticsearch;
- Finally, increasing the size of HEAP to be used for indexing can increase the writing performance. the default size is 10 percent of all heap size.

I hope these points could help you.